# What is the meaning of =! in objective c

Tags: objective-c

!= in most language means not equal
But how about =! in objective C? I found this in the code snippet below.
Thanks

```
- (void) toggleButton: (UIButton *) aButton
{
    if ((_isOn = !_isOn))
    {
        [self setBackgroundImage:BASEGREEN forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setBackgroundImage:PUSHGREEN forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self setTitle:@"On" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitle:@"On" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setBackgroundImage:BASERED forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setBackgroundImage:PUSHRED forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self setTitle:@"Off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTitle:@"Off" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }

    [self relaxButton:self];
}
```

Comment: It would be less confusing as `_isOn = !isOn; if ( _isOn ) { ... } else { ... } ...`

Comment: It first sets _isOn to the "not" of itself, then returns the resulting value to be tested in the if statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A =!B is basically a boolean saying "set A to the opposite of B".

For example, you could do:

```
BOOL a = NO;
BOOL b = !a;
```

and b would then be `YES`.

Your line of code is basically flipping the state of the BOOL is_On, and then the if statement block is being executed if the new state is YES, otherwise the else block is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

`!` is one of the fundamental boolean operators. Along with `||` and  `&&`, `!` is used to manipulate boolean values. Because booleans can only be true or false, boolean operators are easy to understand.

1) The not operator (`!`) is used to reverse the state of a boolean variable. True becomes false and false becomes true after not.

```
 BOOL a = NO;
 a = !a;
 if (a) {
 ...
 // will execute because a is now YES, or true
 }
```

2) The and operator (`&&`) is used on two boolean values. It return true if both values being compared are true. It returns false if any of the values being compared are false

```
BOOL a = NO;
BOOL b = YES;
if (a && b) {
...
// will not execute because NO && YES is NO
}

a = YES;
if (a && b) {
...
// will execute because YES && YES is YES
}
```

3) The or operator (`||`) is also used on two boolean variables. It return true if either one of the booleans in question is true.

```
BOOL a = YES;
BOOL b = NO;
if (a || b) {
...
// will execute because YES || NO is YES
}
```

A truth table is a valuable rescource when thinking about boolean operators

```
true || true = true
true || false = true
false || true = true
false || false = false

true && true = true
true && false = false
false && true = false
false && false = false

!true = false
!false = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misreading it. It's not `_isOn =! _isOn`, it's `_isOn = !_isOn`.  Notice the space between the `=` and the `!`.  A single exclamation is logical negation, i.e., it is toggling the value of `_isOn` and assigning the result back to `_isOn`.

Comment: I think I ask question because I don't understand, right?
Btw, still thanks for giving an answer. :)